# X is not a constructor when trying to import SimpleBar into Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been poking around for hours now, but can't get this to work. I'd like to import [SimpleBar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) in my app, but am failing miserably.

> TypeError: simplebar_1.SimpleBar is not a constructor

I managed to get the npm package working earlier today, but there were some weird issues with resizing and as the npm package only ships with the minified version I resorted to getting the 'real thing'.

I'm trying to wrap this in a directive like so

```
import {
    Directive,
    Input,
    ElementRef,
    AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';

import { SimpleBar } from 'simplebar';

@Directive({
    selector: '[simpleBar]'
})
export class SimpleBarDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        new SimpleBar(this.elementRef.nativeElement, {
            autoHide: true
        });
    }
};
```

However, that gives me the above error message. Luckily I managed to get a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5B05Me9lkdK2WCGrFE9?p=preview) up and running that shows the exact same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's undefined : SimpleBar undefined

Comment: Put a console.log(SimpleBar); after the import and see , it's undefnied, so you're not properly importing it, maybe path is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

In `src/simplebar` you declared the export as default by doing `export default class SimpleBar{....}` and then you imported by using `import {SimpleBar} from 'simplebar'`

You can only import a default export by doing `import SimpleBar from 'simplebar'` without the parenthesis.

The parenthisis import style is used when you want to import multiple things from the file eg -

`import {SimpleBar, SimpleDialog, SimpleModal} from 'simplethings'`

that way there won't be a `default` export in the file.

**THE SOLUTION**

use `import SimpleBar from 'simplebar'` **or** remove the `default` modifier in your class export in `src/simplebar`

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Look at here, the sourcecode of `simplebar`. https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/blob/master/src/simplebar.js

They are using `export default`. They don't export SimpleBar. Therefore, fix your import syntax.

```
import * as SimpleBar from 'simplebar';
```